# Multiple kernel density estimations in one d3.js chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to make a plot that shows density estimations for two different distributions simultaneously, like this:

[image]

The data is in two columns of a CSV file. I've modified code from Mike Bostock's [block on kernel density estimation](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341954), and have managed to make a plot that does what I want, but only if I manually specify the two separate density plots -- see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karawoo/hfdggywd/), particularly beginning at line 66:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(kde(cola))
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .style("fill", "#a6cee3");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(kde(colb))
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .style("fill", "#b2df8a");
```

I've tried various incantations with `map()` to try to get the data into a single object that can be used to set the color of each density area according to the `color` domain, e.g.:

```
var columns = color.domain().map(function(column) {
    return {
        column: column,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {kde: kde(d[column])};
        })
    };
});
```

I don't have a great grasp of what `map()` does, but this definitely does not work.

How can I structure my data to make this plot in a less brittle way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this generic and remove column dependency first prepare your data:

```
var newData = {};
// Columns should be numeric
data.forEach(function(d) {
    //iterate over all the keys
    d3.keys(d).forEach(function(col){
        if (!newData[col])
            newData[col] = [];//create an array if not present.
        newData[col].push(+d[col])
    });
});
```

Now `newData` will hold the data like this

```
{ 
  a:[123, 23, 45 ...], 
  b: [34,567, 45, ...]
}
```

Next make the color domain like this:

```
var color = d3.scale.category10()
        .domain(d3.keys(newData))//this will return the columns
        .range(["#a6cee3", "#b2df8a"]);
```

Finally make your area chart like this:

```
d3.keys(newData).forEach(function(d){
    svg.append("path")
            .datum(kde(newData[d]))
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("d", area)
            .style("fill", color(d));
})
```

So now the code will have no dependency over the column names and its generic.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h4gfto5j/)